# Java inheritance with super();

Tags: java, inheritance

I am studying java inheritance, and confused of the issue below.

when class B inherits class A,

we simply write as

```
class B extends A{

}
```

when I created new B object,

```
B b = new B();
```

before the creation of b, JVM internally creates super class`s object with super();

```
super();
```

so, is that b actually inherits that parent class`s object?

I bring this issue because the code below makes me confuse.

```
class HumanCalculator {
    String madeBy;

    HumanCalculator(String madeBy){
        this.madeBy = madeBy;
    }

}

class CompCalculator extends HumanCalculator {
    CompCalculator(String madeBy){
        super(madeBy);
    }
}

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CompCalculator test = new CompCalculator("USA");

        System.out.println(test.madeBy);
    }
}
```

the CompCalculator constructor actually has no

```
this.madeBy = madeBy;
```

but the result is USA,

so again the question is,

"is that b actually inherits that parent class`s object which is created by super()?"

Comment: `super(madeBy);` calls `HumanCalculator(madeBy)` (which then assigns `this.madeBy`) as you correctly stated at first, so why are you confused?

Comment: Yes it does and madeBy that you are getting as USA is coming from parent class.

Answer (score 1):

> before the creation of b, JVM internally creates super class`s object with super();

No. A single object is created, of type B. The constructor of the superclass (A) is called when calling super(). This constructor does its part of the job, before the remaining instructions of the B constructor are executed.

In your concrete example, the HumanCalculator constructor initializes the field `madeBy` of the object, of type CompCalculator, that is being created.

Comment: thanks for your help, no offense but I doubt your answer. I am reading java text book, and found that if one class inherits the other class, and if that sub class creates a new object, JVM internally calls super(); am I wrong? and If that parent class has none-default constructer, we cannot omit calling super(), but to call something like super(madeBy)

Comment: That's correct. What's wrong is that calling super doesn't create another object as you think it does. It initializes the **sinlge** object, of type B, that is being created. If you want to create a flying car, you don't first create a first car, and then create another car with wings. You create a single car. First you add all the stuff that a car needs (that's what the super call does: it initializes the wheels, engine, etc. of the flying car), then you add wings to the car (that's what the subclass constructor does: it initializes the wings and the altimeter of the flying car)

Answer (score 0):

Objects don't inherit other objects. Classes can inherit other classes. Objects of one class C can be used "as if it were objects of the superclasses of C".

When you say `CompCalculator extends HumanCalculator`, `CompCalculator` will have the members of `HumanCalculator`. This is why it can be used as if it were a `HumanCalculator`.

The `super` constructor call is just saying "just construct a `CompCalculator` by following the steps of constructing a `HumanCalculator`". You can do this because `CompCalculator` has the members of `HumanCalculator`. `CompCalculator` has a field called `madeBy`, just like `HumanCalculator` has `madeBy` as well. That's why the line in `HumanCalculator` will run successfully.

Usually, after calling `super`, you would do some more initialisation that is unique to the subclass. Just calling `super` and doing nothing else is quite a special case.